# How can I disable Ctrl+Shift+Arrow from causing my screen to flip?

Tags: windows, display, amd-catalyst, flip

Windows 7 Home Premium, Catalyst Control Center.

Without any apparent reason, after booting my PC, I got this little balloon "HD 4600 Drivers updated". I did not install any new cards or drivers or anything.

But now, when I try to select an entire word by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> my screen flips left to right and upside down.

Where can I disable this annoying shortcut?

OR

Any other way of selecting the entire word?

**There is no option for this in Catalyst Control Center.**

Comment: If you've found a solution then please post an answer (yes, to your own question, it's perfectly acceptable)! In the meantime, I've added a community wiki post that contains the information you provided, feel free to add and accept your own answer post with further details if you wish and I shall delete me CW placeholder.

Comment: How often do we press this combination a day? I mean, no offense but don't press them!

Comment: I think I (and tens of thousands of programmers and developers around the world with me) press this combination maybe **2 or 3 hundred** times a day. It is the only way to select the entire word infront of the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*Information provided by the asker in a question edit:*</sub>

Killing a program called "SoftOSM" prevents the shortcut from causing the screen to flip.

Comment: This is a bad, temporary solution. To completely disable the shortcut, check Denver's answer.

Comment: As terrible and temporary as it is, does it deserve down-votes? I don't think so. Please state if this would cause any "real" problem further down the line before down-voting.

Answer (score 27):

I just ran into this exact issue, and found the solution.  I use CTRL+ALT+DOWN to duplicate a line of text in Eclipse, so when it flipped my screen I was somewhat perplexed :)  My OS is Windows 7 64-bit and here is where the hotkeys can be edited or disabled.

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click on "Appearance and Personalization"
3. Click on "Display"
4. Click on "Change Display Settings" in the left
5. Click on "Advanced Settings"
6. Click on "Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel" tab **
7. Click on "Graphics Properties" button
8. Select "Advanced Mode" and click "OK"
9. Click on "Options and Support" in the bottom-left of the dialog

And voila!  You can now change or disable the hotkeys.

This is specific to Intel graphics cards, and if your video card is not Intel then this tab will not be there and the instructions from this point onward will not be useful!

Screenshot of screen where the hotkeys can be edited or disabled:

[image: Screenshot of screen where the hotkeys can be edited or disabled]

Comment: Worked for me on my Lenovo ThinkPad T530 running Windows 7. Thanks!  One note: If you have Control Panel in "advanced mode," step 2 should be skipped; "Appearance and Personalization" doesn't appear in the Control Panel, but "Display" does.

Comment: Toshiba Satellite S70t-b running Windows 8 (with touch screen)

Comment: Using Intel HD Graphics Control Panel 4400 driver 10.18.10.3574, this does not work.  Even after changing the hot keys, Ctrl-Shift-Left rotates the screen (though the other arrow keys don't!); disabling the hot keys, Ctrl-Shift-Left does nothing (does not select text).

Comment: I got there via "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items" and going to "Intel ® HD Graphics", then "Options and Support" and the "Hot Key Manager" tab, then selecting "Disable" under "Manage Hot Keys".

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Intel graphics processor, you can right-click on your desktop and select Graphics Options > Hot Keys > Disable:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

you can often select a word by doubleclicking on it, triple clicking to select a whole paragraph. You can also allegedly (i run intel and nvidia mostly) change the key combo from ATI catalyst control center.

Comment: I am a software developer and I cannot use my mouse for this. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

you display hotkeys are enabled , right click on the desktop ,  the context menu should have an option to disable it , else go to your graphics cards control panel and disable it

Comment: There is no hotkeys option in the context menu, I cannot find this option in Catalyst control center.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD video card:

- right click on desktop, choose "AMD VISION Engine Control Center" (or otherwise get in there)
- on the control center, top right there is a "preferences" button that has white text. click it and choose "hot keys"
- you can easily disable or reassign the screen rotation hot keys

Frankly just needing to do this shows that some team at AMD really screwed up. Anyhow at least they had the good sense to all customization.