# How do I get Ctrl + Shift + arrow keys to highlight blocks of text in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, shortcuts

Currently Ctrl + Shift + Arrow keys changes the orientation of my screen!  Apparently it can highlight text, but I don't know how to get that functionality.  How do I get it to stop changing the orientation of my screen and start highlighting text?

Comment: Look in the settings for your graphics driver. There's probably an icon for it in your notification area.

Comment: Could it be related to this: http://superuser.com/questions/303789/how-can-i-disable-ctrlshiftarrow-from-causing-my-screen-to-flip?

Answer (score 2):

Windows by itself can not control your video display in such a way.
Screen orientation change is controlled by display drivers.

Easiest way to check/disable this is to:
[1a] Go to your Control Panel -> Display -> Change display settings
[1b] Or right click empty space on your Desktop -> select Screen resolution
 
[2] Click Advanced settings

Now click on the tab for your graphic card, you'll notice it by a looong name.
It will have something like 'AMD Control Center', 'Intel Graphic Driver' 'Catalyst Control' or similar.

Now there should be A LOT of options, but the one you need is the one that deals with Hot Keys.
For every graphic card manufacturer it's in a different place, but the option is there.

Find it and disable the hotkeys. If it still doesn't work, go back and edit hotkeys to something else.
For example - CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F11.

Let me know how it goes :-)